# Exact word for the material which is used to thread Tennis racquets

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I am a non-native English speaker, I have searched a lot in google to find the exact word for the material which is used to thread Tennis racquets or the material which is used to connect the fishing hook and the fishing rod. But i did not find any. Can anybody tell me what's the exact word for that.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tennis ***String***

The material used for a long time to *string* a Tennis racket (racquet is use more in club names than in daily use) is [Catgut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catgut)

> Natural gut is still used as a high-performance string in tennis racquets, although it had more popularity in the past and is being displaced by synthetic strings.

Fishing ***Line***

For [fishing *lines*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishing_line), the materials are more diverse

> Modern fishing lines intended for spinning, spin cast, or bait casting reels are almost entirely made from artificial substances, including nylon, polyvinylidene fluoride (PVDF, and called fluorocarbon), polyethylene, Dacron and Dyneema (UHMWPE). The most common type is monofilament, made of a single strand.

---

**RE Racket vs Racquet:**

At www.wilson.com/en-us/ and www.wilson.com/en-gb/ the word is racket however they sell Wilson racquets AND rackets at amazon

Amazon.com:

[image]

Amazon.co.uk:

[image]

Comment: This is true, but it might be worth mentioning that, on a tennis racquet, the material is usually just called the _string_, and, in fishing, it's called the _line_. So, I'd usually say, "My racquet broke a string," or "My [fishing] line snapped."

Comment: Done, also mentioned the modern spelling of racket

Comment: Is there a bit of a UK/US divide between *racquet* and *racket*? http://grammarist.com/spelling/racket-racquet/ says the preference for *racket* is stronger in the US, I would say *much* stronger, but in a quick search CNN was using  *racquet*.